Existence/Non-Existence of operators on $l^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ with a specified norm.
Today one of my friend had asked me about giving an example of a bounded linear operator $T$ on a Banach space $X$ such that the family $\{T^n\,\text{:}\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ which is NOT equicontinuous but the family $\{\frac{T^n}{n}\,\text{:}\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is equicontinuous. While solving the problem I came up with the following example :
Define, $T:l^\infty(\mathbb{N})\to l^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ by, $T(x_1,x_2,\dots)=(x_1+x_2,x_3,\dots)$. Then I have shown that $\parallel T^n\parallel=n+1\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. This serves the purpose. But then something strike up in my mind and I tried to think about a new problem in a similar line.
Problem : Given any sequence $\{c_n\}$ of positive real numbers does there exist a bounded linear operator $T$ on $l^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ for which $\parallel T^n\parallel=c_n$ ? All I can do is to prove a necessary condition ie. if such a $T$ exists then $\{c_n\}$ must satisfy $c_n\leq c_kc_l$ whenever $k+l=n$ and $k,l\in\mathbb{N}$. Can we impose some extra condition on the sequence so that such a $T$ exists ?
P.S. I am not looking for a complete solution. Some hints will be much appreciated. Thank you.

We of course need $c_0 = 1$. Then let $T(e_n) = e_{n + 1} \cdot \frac{c_{n + 1}}{c_n}$. This gives $T^k(e_n) = e_{n + k} \cdot \frac{c_{n+k}}{c_n}$ and $\|T^k\| = \sup_n \frac{c_{n+k}}{c_n}$.
Your condition, rewritten as $\frac{c_{n+k}}{c_n} \leq c_k$, gives that this $\sup$ is equal to $c_k$, achieved when $n = 0$.

Aah I solved it just now. I was going to post it but then I saw your solution. Did the exactly same thing. Cheers!
